# Why divs height could not expand in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome

I am trying to show images with description in divs, it works fine in all browsers, but in Chrome, divs height won't adapt to its content height ..

Here is my code, I hope it can be clear, the problem shows up in chrome only

```
css:
===========
.mainDiv{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    top: 10px;
    min-height: 700px;
}

.borde{
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #acb0b2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #acb0b2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #acb0b2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#acb0b2')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#acb0b2');
    border: solid 1px #d4d1d2;

}
===========

js:
===========
// this will arrange the divs into the page
function divPlace(count){
    var top         = 0;
    var right       = 0;
    var maxWidth    = $("#mainDiv").width() -200 ;
    var level       = 0;
    var heightArray = new Array();
    var counter     = 0;
    var windowWidth = parseInt(maxWidth/200);

    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        if(right > maxWidth){
            right=0;
            level=level+1;
            counter=0;

        }

        $("#div_"+i).css("right", right+"px");
        right=right+250;

        if(level==0){
             $("#div_"+i).css("top", "0px");        
             $("#div_"+i).css("height", $("#div_"+i).height());
             heightArray[counter] =  $("#div_"+i).height();
        }else{
            $("#div_"+i).css("top", 15+heightArray[counter]+"px");
            $("#div_"+i).css("height", $("#div_"+i).height());
            heightArray[counter] =  $("#div_"+i).height()+heightArray[counter]+15;
        }

        counter++;
    }
}
===========

html
===========
<div class="mainDiv" id="mainDiv">

    <div class="borde" id="div_0">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="borde" id="div_1">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="borde" id="div_2">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" />
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(doucment).ready(function(){
        divPlace(22);
    });
</script>
===========
```

The problem is that divs will not expand automatically to contain the images inside in chrome

Here is the result in Chrome
[image]

Here is the result in FireFox, notice how divs heights have expanded to fill the inner images

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to ask how you can clone a technique without any effort. Please show us the code you're using and explain what you mean by _template_.

Comment: Ok, I will prepare a good description of what I have, stay tuned :-)

Comment: Please see the question again, as I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your calling to JavaScript like this:

```
$("#mainDiv img").load(function(){
 divPlace(22);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one.. needs to be paid though.

http://themify.me/themes/pinboard

Comment: I thought its easy to find a free one .. I don't want a whole theme, I just need the template to show the image with different height and little text under it ..

Comment: I tried, but I got too many results out there .. I thought people who already used this will be helpful ..

Comment: i see. if thats the case, i can't help you. not with a responsive one at least.

Comment: lots of naked pictures pictures in the demo .. I felt shy that I couldn't continue looking to see if it suits me ..